# PHP strpos and strlen

Tags: php, strpos, strlen

I'm trying to get words before and after a string in a $body thats taken from a mysql entry.  I'm able to find the keyword in the body, get its strpos and its strlen.  From there I believe I should be able to tell it to print X characters (or ideally words) before and after that but I can't seem to find anything on google telling me HOW.  Is there a PHP function that tells it to start at $strpos and then somehow use the strlen and print before and after that?

Hope that wasn't too unclear, any help is appreciated - thanks.
I got the original strpos and strlen idea from Amandas answer here:
[Return words before and after the first occurrence of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441536/return-words-before-and-after-the-first-occurrence-of-a-string)

But I don't understand how to apply that.

Comment: Post some input and example output of this function. I don't follow your question very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: that looks like its going to work for me, thanks! Don't know why I couldn't find that on google, guess I was searching for the wrong thing.  Will check answer when it lets me in 5 minutes.